# How to find equivalent command in bash Azure CLI for powershell command?

Tags: bash, azure, powershell, bgp

What would be the bash equivalent of powershell Get-AzureRmBgpServiceCommunity ?

Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/get-azurermbgpservicecommunity?view=azurermps-6.13.0) does not give any bash options. Am I looking at the wrong place ?

Comment: FWIW, the docs on the Bash CLI are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest). Finding command equivalents (when they exist) is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

> az network route-filter rule list-service-communities

Documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/route-filter/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-route-filter-rule-list-service-communities